# Why do C++ deprecated warnings print twice?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

If I have

```cpp
namespace foo {
    inline int bar() {
        return 1119;
    }
}

__attribute__((deprecated)) inline int bar() {
    return 138;
}
```

in `header.h` and

```cpp
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = bar();
    int y = foo::bar();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```

in `source.cpp`, then

```sh
g++ source.cpp -o deprecated-test
```

results in

```
source.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source.cpp:5:17: warning: ‘int bar()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     int x = bar();
                 ^
In file included from source.cpp:1:
header.h:7:40: note: declared here
 __attribute__((deprecated)) int bar() {
                                 ^~~
source.cpp:5:17: warning: ‘int bar()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     int x = bar();
                 ^
In file included from source.cpp:1:
header.h:7:40: note: declared here
 __attribute__((deprecated)) int bar() {
```

(on Ubuntu 18.10 with g++ 8.2.0).

**Why does the deprecated warning print twice?**

Heading off some suggestions that would be unhelpful:

- `[[deprecated]]`:
  I know with C++14 on you can use the `[[deprecated]]` attribute, but I need to work with C++11.
- Declaration vs. definition: [The docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) seem to imply it should be used with function declaration rather than definition, but

  1. I need to define the functions `inline` in a header rather than declare in the header and define in source files; and
  2. Trying this approach didn't stop the warning from printing twice anyway.

Comment: Might be a bug. Clang doesn't print two warnings. `[[deprecated]]` produces the same results (two warnings in gcc, one in clang).

Comment: @tkausl thanks, good to know! Seeing as clang doesn't print the warning twice, I may have to try out other `g++` versions as well to see if it's a recently introduced and/or recently fixed bug

Comment: gcc versions up to 5.5 even print _three_ warnings... Interesting. https://godbolt.org/z/383Hl0

Comment: @tkausl Wow... Also, thanks for pointing me toward the godbolt.org resource. I've seen it before, but forgotten all about it and didn't think to look there to try out other compilers

Comment: If you are building your program in parallel, then you might get the same error from multiple compilation units before the build shuts down.

Comment: @tkausl Looks like only gcc 5.x prints 3 warnings. gcc 7.x prints one warning, all others (that I checked) print two warnings. Taking the address of a deprecated function prints two warnings with gcc 5.x, and one warning for all other versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of GCC 8.2.0:

> The deprecated attribute results in a warning **if the function is used anywhere
>   in the source file**. This is useful when identifying functions that are expected
>   to be removed in a future version of a program. The warning also includes the
>   location of the declaration of the deprecated function, to enable users to easily
>   find further information about why the function is deprecated, or what they
>   should do instead. Note that the warnings only occurs for uses...

There should be only one warning and not two. So this is a bug in GCC.

There is a related bug for Type attributes (rather than Function attributes) titled:   [C/C++ `__attribute__((deprecated))` does not appear to wrap declarations as implied from the doc.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43778)

It has been confirmed as a bug.

Comment: It is certainly a bug in GCC and not a problem with my code as you (and others from the comments to the post) mention. The related bug you mention is interested, as they don't get multiple warnings from one usage, but rather warnings on declarations that are *not* used. It looks like I'll need to file a separate bug report. Thanks!